# Java: How to find timestamp at the end of the month for a given timezone

Tags: java, jodatime

I have a requirement to find the timestamp at the end of the month for a given time zone from a given timestamp.

The following code returns the start of the month timestamp in UTC

```
DateTime allInOneLine = new DateTime( DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" ) ).plusMonths( 1 ).dayOfMonth().withMinimumValue().withTimeAtStartOfDay();
```

returns:

```
2017-12-01T00:00:00.000Z
```

Any suggestions how I can get end month timestamp for a given timezone

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#lastDayOfMonth--

Comment: Just take the start of the next month and subtract 1ms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is a good starting point. I have passed in UTC , this can be made generic for any timezone

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters;
import static java.time.ZoneOffset.UTC;

public class TruncateToMonth {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now(UTC);
        ZonedDateTime truncatedToMonth = now.with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth()).with(LocalTime.MAX);
        System.out.println(truncatedToMonth);
        System.out.println(truncatedToMonth.toInstant().getEpochSecond());
    }
}
```